# challenging integral involving $\zeta(5)$

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-zeta

I ran across a curious integral that seems to be rather tough that some on the site may enjoy.

Show that $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{1-x^{2}\sin^{2}(x)}dx = \frac{5\sqrt[5]{{\pi}^{8}}}{32\sqrt[5]{{\zeta(5)}^{9}}}$$

How in the world can $\zeta(5)$ be incorporated into this?.  I tried series and several methods, but made no real progress. Any ideas?.  Thanks very much.

Comment: This one is really tough!

Comment: Where did you see this relation?

Comment: I saw it on a site where someone had posted the solution but no method. At mymathforum.com.  I checked this closed form against the numerical solution that Maple and Mathematica gave and it was exactly as posted. I do not know where the poster may have came up with it, but it appears to be correct.

Comment: I computed both sides to 20 places in Maple.  It concluded they agree only to 8 places, and differ by about $2 \times 10^{-9}$.

Answer (score 19):

The purported identity is *false*, as GEdgar already indicated in the comment, but remarkably accurate:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2 \sin^2(x)} \mathrm{d} x &\approx& \color{red}{ 0.91392913}60302011781728596 \\
    \frac{5 \pi^{8/5}}{32 \zeta(5)^{9/5}} &\approx& \color{red}{0.91392913}77247633495515212
   \end{eqnarray}
$$

Here is the *Mathematica* code used:

```
In[19]:= N[
 NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 - x^2]/(1 - x^2 Sin[x]^2), {x, 0, 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 60], 25]

Out[19]= 0.9139291360302011781728596

In[20]:= N[(5 Pi^(8/5))/(32 Zeta[5]^(9/5)), 25]

Out[20]= 0.9139291377247633495515212

In[21]:= % - %%

Out[21]= 1.694562171378662*10^-9
```

Comment: I appreciate you, for you saved my time from a deceptive non-identity!

Comment: I am so sorry.  I apologize for misleading. Apparently, I did not check far enough and took it on faith. I do not know from where the poster derived this.  From now on I will make sure before I post. Again...sorry.   Here is the link to the problem if you wan to look at it:  http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=25093&sid=00d5bff5795bc118e4005881795dda51

Comment: @Cody We must always check the OP proposed answer before we try anything. Anyway, your question is still quite interesting.